# Is there a linguistic term for replacing past tense verb with present tense?

Tags: phonology, verbs, dialects

In my dialect of English (North West England), we sometimes use the present tense of a verb when standard English employs the past tense, such as in the sentence below:

> "I waits for the bus yesterday, but it never come..."

Contrasted with the RP "

> I was waiting for the bus yesterday..."

or

> "I waited for the bus yesterday..."

Using "waits", the present tense, instead of "waited", which is the "correct" past tense of the word. Is there a term for this phenomenon?

Comment: This is unvoluntarily comical because the present tense of *I waited" is not *I waits* in formal grammar. I'm sure you know, just saying. That's probably the dry Brittish humour we hear so much about, init? It might be important if *-s* reflects a different inflection than bare indicative present tense. I think Bavarian or Frankish would occasionally add *-s*, too "; it could be similar to the apparently self reflexive verbs, like in Slavic *-sja*; we could compare the *-s* in past tense *was*.

Comment: I'd even compare the platization of *t, tt* to *tz* in Old High Ger., past *tzt* would likely elide. Your forefathers didn't come from the mainland by any chance, hundreds of years ago?

Comment: I've heard the generalization of present -s to all singular subjects in American English as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes this phenomenon is known as the **narrative present** or (especially by Latinists) **historical present**.

Another potential phenomenon going on is that your dialect has developed **relative tense**. You might be used to descriptions of language with absolute tense - tense that is in relation to the present, but some languages use some tense relative to a reference point sometimes not the present), frequently contextually determined and dynamically moving to a new point in time when the narrative needs changes focus.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is "Historical present". It's quite frequent in French in textbooks.
You may also be interested in reading this section in wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aorist_(Ancient_Greek)#Narrative